# Cannot install package via nuget

Tags: visual-studio-2015, nuget, umbraco

Have been trying a clean install of `umbraco` all afternoon in `Visual Studio 2015`. I am receiving complaints about a particular package `ImageProcessor`. Just trying to install it this package separately yields the same not very helpful message. These things are supposed to *just* work aren't they?

Interestingly I can install anything up to and including version `2.3.2`

Exasperated I uninstalled VS 2015 and reinstalled. Also removed nuget from that and re-added it. No idea how we are supposed to "debug" these things hoping someone with similar pain in the past can share a solution. This is the gist of it:

```
> PM> install-package imageprocessor Attempting to gather dependency
> information for package 'imageprocessor.2.3.3' with respect to project
> 'Show.Umbraco', targeting '.NETFramework,Version=v4.5.1' Attempting to
> resolve dependencies for package 'imageprocessor.2.3.3' with
> DependencyBehavior 'Lowest' Resolving actions to install package
> 'imageprocessor.2.3.3' Resolved actions to install package
> 'imageprocessor.2.3.3' Install failed. Rolling back... Package
> 'ImageProcessor.2.3.3' does not exist in project 'Show.Umbraco'
> Package 'ImageProcessor.2.3.3' does not exist in folder
> 'C:\_dev\Show\Show.Umbraco\packages' install-package : Could not
> install package 'ImageProcessor 2.3.3'. You are trying to install this
> package into a project that targets '.NETFramework,Version=v4.5.1',
> but the package does not contain any assembly references or content
> files that are  compatible with that framework. For more information,
> contact the package author. At line:1 char:1
> + install-package imageprocessor
> + ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
>     + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [Install-Package], Exception
>     + FullyQualifiedErrorId : NuGetCmdletUnhandledException,NuGet.PackageManagement.PowerShellCmdlets.InstallPackageCommand
```

Comment: Your project if I read that correctly is targeting a version of the .Net Framework that is earlier than what is supported by ImageProcessor. ImageProcessor package is a dependency of UmbracoCms.

Comment: but i can install a previous version 2.3.2 just fine? anyhoo i tried 4.5 through 4.6,1, all roads lead to pompeii

Comment: FWIW i've forced an earlier version of Umbraco (7.3.8) with nuget which brings in ImageProcessor 2.3.2 OK targeting .NET 4.6.1 This will have to do for now.

Comment: Since 4.5.1 isn't really supported by MS, I'm not surprised that that package wasn't compiled for it. I find it hard to believe 4.5.2 or 4.6.* don't work though. Have you tried a new project or solution that targets one of them and just install image processor?

Comment: yes this is a new project in VS 2015 default target 4.6.1

Comment: have the same problem, completely unrelated to umbraco. Cannot add any nuget package reference via visual studio. Commandline nuget works, though. Haven't you by chance reinstall you VS lately?

Answer (score 1):

Are you using Visual Studio 2015 Update 2?

I've had the same issue, and have been getting really frustrated.

The solution, was to open the project in a previous version of Visual Studio (Visual Studio 2013) I installed UmbracoCms 7.4.3 (including ImageProcessor) without issue!

Comment: Yes had this an option. I've gone the manual install route.Would love to know the cause and the fix.